# Test name as given with collect-only

Tags: pytest

I would like to access the name of the current test as a string in my tests to write some VCD log-files.

Is the name as given when I run `pytest --collect-only` available as a fixture or equivalent?

**Example:**

Running `pytest --collect-only` yields (shorted):

```
    <Class TestFooBar>
        <Function test_30_foobar[1-A]>
```

In my test I would like to access the above string `test_30_foobar[1-A]`.

Is there a (simple) way?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer for my own question. It's hidden in the `request` *fixture*. See the following thereof derived fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def name_test(request):
    """Make name of test available as string and escaped as filename"""
    import types
    i = types.SimpleNamespace()
    i.name = request.node.name
    i.filename = i.name.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '')
    return i
```

The `filename` variable is a clumsily escaped string that should be a valid filename. However, only tested on POSIX so far.